# OCZ SSD not working after secure erase failed

Tags: linux, ssd, debian, secure-erase, hp-proliant

I tried to secure erase the 60GB OCZ-VERTEX2 SSD in my HP N40L MicroServer using the Disks GUI tool on the debian-live-10.7.0-amd64-lxde.iso. It failed the first time and unfortunately I don't remember the error it threw.

Then I tried manually secure erase with `hdparm` from the terminal with user password `TEST`, without success.

When I connect the SSD and immediately run `user@debian:/sbin$ sudo ./hdparm -I /dev/sdb` I get the following output:

```
/dev/sdb:
 
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       OCZ-VERTEX2                             
    Serial Number:      OCZ-9QHU0R5W81479602
    Firmware Revision:  1.35    
    Transport:          Serial
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0028) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   117231408
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   117231408
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:       57241 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:       60022 MBytes (60 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 1
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
            Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 1 block)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
Security: 
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    400min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 400min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5e83a97f0f49e740
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : e83a97
    Unique ID   : f0f49e740
Checksum: correct
```

However the second time I run it, I get:

```
user@debian:/sbin$ sudo ./hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
```

or

```
user@debian:/sbin$ sudo ./hdparm -I /dev/sdb
 
/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 40 e0 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 
ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   0   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   0   0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0
```

From the Disks GUI tool I'm unable to properly erase or format it and I can't install Debian to this disk either.

Is there something I can try to get this drive working again?

Comment: That's a rather old drive. Has it reached or nearing its maximum writes? What usage has it had previously?

Comment: Also, the title says it failed AFTER a secure erase, implying the secure erase process completed, but the question itself notes it failed DURING multiple attempted secure erase processes, you were not able to securely erase the drive successfully, and now the drive appears to not be working/responding. Please use the EDIT button to clarify what exactly is the case. Titles can also be edited.

Comment: Good point, I clarified it. Secure erase didn't finish successfully. The drive spent years in storage, then used it for a year or so as OS drive for Open Media Vault. It was working fine before trying Secure Erase. I regret trying it...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue cannot be reconstructed. There is no way to know for certain what the issue was originally, or what the correct solution would be due to the equipment being sold and the part beginning to work under uncertain circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drive works now, but I wasn't able to pinpoint the issue. I tried the SSD today via an eSATA dock connected to my Synology NAS. I was able to format and use the drive normally. Then tried with a USB2 dock connected to my MacBook and I was able to erase the drive from Disk Utility (with the option to write random data to the disk turned on, to enhance security). I was also able to copy files to the drive and verified with MD5 checksums that the files were written properly. So it seems the drive is working fine. Perhaps the Debian live USB environment wasn't ideal. I sold my HP N40L MicroServer today so I can't test again under the same circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

`$ sudo apt install smartmontools` will make smartctl available (among other things)

Then, I use this to determine selected runtime changes

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb \
| grep --color=auto -E \
  '^(Device M|ID#|  2|  3|  5| 10|183|184|187|188|196|197|198|201|241|243)'
```

... I have yet to see a failed drive, so cannot advice exactly what to look for - I'm tracking CHANGES currently.
*(I log this to a file, occasionally, and use `diff` to se what changed).*

This
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes
... may help to understand the values shown.

These

```
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct  
183 Runtime_Bad_Block  
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt  
196 Reallocated_Event_Count
```

... and similar might be the most interesting to verify for an disk that has actually failed.
Which ones of the above actually shows up - for a certain disk - depends on drive and make; and it may differ wildly, as it seems.

Example output from the above:

```
Device Model:     HGST HUH721212ALN604
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   133   133   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       93
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   184   184   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       366 (Average 348)
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```